# Selecting connected subgraph that exceeds value c, with least possible weight

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a graph $G$ where each node has a value $c$ and weight $w$, I want to select a connected subgraph $V^*$, such that,

1. Sum of all values in  $V^*$ crosses threshold $t$.
2. Sum of all weights(say $w^*$) in $V^*$ is as low as possible.

A practical example is finding smallest continuous area of a country that hosts at least $x\%$ of the population. In this case, value would be population, and weight would be area.

I found a [related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93877/largest-weight-limited-connected-subgraph-np-complete), but it only asks about the complexity, not the algorithm.

I thought of 0 - 1 knapsack, such that values and weights swap role. So,

1. Size of knapsack is $t$, however we are allowed to cross it once.
2. minimize $w^*$.

However, I think this won't work, mainly because we can't order the nodes by $value/weights$, and secondly because of ability to exceed knapsack size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard.
Let $S = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be an instance of partition.
Create a clique $G$ on $n$ nodes $v_1, \dots, v_n$.
Set both the cost and the weight of $v_i$ to $x_i$.
Set $t = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x_i \in S} x_i$.

If there is a subset $C$ of $S$ such that $2 \sum_{x_i \in C} x_i = \sum_{x_i \in S} x_i$, then the set of vertices $\{v_i \mid x_i \in C\}$ is connected, has total value $t$ and total weight $t$.

If there is no subset $C$ of $S$ such that $2 \sum_{x_i \in C} x_i = \sum_{x_i \in S} x_i$ then every subset of vertices of $G$ either has total value smaller than $t$ (and hence is not a feasible solution), or has a total value larger than $t$, and hence also weight larger than $t$.

Then you have that the answer to the instance of partition is yes if and only if the optimal solution to your problem has measure (total weight) $t$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you used clique, as general graph case is at least as hard as clique. cost and weight can be set to same, as weights are redundant due to forming it as a graph partitioning problem. The part I didn't understand however, is why sum of weights of C, has to be exactly t? The problem allows it to be larger than t. Or is this simplification not harder than original one? If so, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: In your problem the sum of the values (not weights!) does not need to be exactly $t$. However, the minimum value of any feasible solution will be at least $t$ and, in my reduction (due to how it is constructed), the weight equals the value so the goal is to find a solution that minimizes its value, provided that it is at least $t$.
What I have shown is that there is a solution with value/weight exactly $t$ (the best you can hope for) if and only if the solution to the instance of partition is "yes". Therefore a poly-time solution to your problem would also solve partition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another reduction from minimum Steiner tree that also shows that your problem is *strongly* NP-hard.

Let $\langle G, T \rangle$ be an instance of minimum Steiner tree, where $G=(V,E)$ is a graph and $T$ is a set of terminals. Let $w_e$ be the weight of edge $e$ in $G$ and assume that all $w_e$ are positive.

Construct a new graph $G'$ by starting from $G$ and splitting each edge $e$ by adding vertex $v_e$, i.e., replace $e=(u,v)$ with the two edges $(u, v_e)$ and $(v_e, v)$. Assign weight $w_e$ to each $v_e$.
Assign value $1$ to all vertices in $T$.  All unspecified weights/values are $0$.

An instance of your problem consists of the graph $G'$ and the threshold $t=|T|$.

A Steiner tree $S=(V',E')$ of $G$ having weight at most $W$ can be converted into a subgraph $H$ of $G'$ with weight $W$ and value $t$. Simply chose $H$ as the subgraph of $G'$ induced by the vertices in $V' \cup \{v_e \mid e \in E'\}$.

Similarly, a solution $H=(V',E')$ of weight $W$ to your problem must contain all terminals and can be converted into a Steiner tree $S$ with weight at most $W$ by taking any spanning tree of the subgraph $G_H$ of $G$ induced by the edges in $\{ e \in E \mid v_e \in V'\}$. Notice that if $H$ is an *optimal* solution to your problem then $G_H$ is already tree (this is ensured by the condition $w_e > 0$).